# SORT(),vector<pair<int,int> > strictly on the basis of key value even if two key value is same

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, stl

From the below code I want to sort the `vector<pair<int,int> >` using `sort()` in STL. But, the problem is that I want to `sort()` the `vector<pair<int,int> >` **strictly** on the basis of **key** even if **two keys are equal**. The value which was inserted first should come first.

Here my code goes:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long int n,k;
    cin>>n>>k;
    vector<pair<int,int> >a;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        int temp;
        cin>>temp;
        a.push_back(make_pair(temp%k,temp));
    }
    sort(a.begin(),a.end());
    vector<pair<int,int> >::iterator it;
    for(it=a.begin();it!=a.end();it++) {
        cout<< it->second<<" ";
    }
   return 0;
}
```

**Input:**

let's take a basic input:

> 2 7
>   17 10

Here both key value `17%7=3` and `10%7=3`.

So I want the output 17 10 only because as key is same so, the element which is entered first should come first.

But that's not the case instead,
**Output** is :

> 10 17

Many different approach is possible. But, I want to solve this problem using sort() only. What changes can i do for my code?

Comment: Use std::stable_sort.

Comment: Where does the `% 3` come from?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt It's `% 7`, from the second input to the entire program. (Not that `14%7 == 3`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `operator<` for `std::pair` compares the `first` member first, and if those are equal, it then compares the `second` member. Since you want to ignore the `second` member, you can't use that default ordering. You can specify a comparison to use instead by passing a lambda as an extra argument to `sort`:

```
std::sort(a.begin(), a.end(),
    [](const std::pair<int,int>& p1, const std::pair<int,int>& p2)
    { return p1.first < p2.first; }); // Not quite there...
```

But that won't get you what you want either:

> The value which was inserted first should come first.

`std::sort` doesn't guarantee anything like that.  You know only that the final result obeys the ordering, but the order of equivalent elements is unspecified.  But the similar function [`std::stable_sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort) does act the way you want.  So:

```
std::stable_sort(a.begin(), a.end(),
    [](const std::pair<int,int>& p1, const std::pair<int,int>& p2)
    { return p1.first < p2.first; });
```

Comment: Thanks,it worked and also got to learn about stable_sort much more deeply.

Answer (score 1):

If I got correctly what you want, you need a so-called "stable sort", and the standard library does provide an aptly-named `std::stable_sort` that you should use instead of plain `std::sort`.